# How to write a compression algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, compression

I need some help coming up with a simple compression algorithm.

I have two lists of unsigned shorts - one for input, and one for output. The input list starts with a few thousand values, and the output list starts empty.

I'm trying to replace repetitive runs of the same value in the input with a 'decompression instruction' value in the output.

I want it to scan the next 2-15 values ahead of the input position, then scan 2-120 values behind the input position, and the best match found would then be added to the output as a single value rather than the entire run. This value essentially is a 'decompression instruction', and is equal to 2*(a+(b*512)+8192), where 'a' is the distance scanned back and 'b' is the distance scanned forward. All such values would therefore fall into the 16384-32767 range. If no match was found, then the value at the input position is copied literally.

This would yield an output where, in order to decompress it in the future, all values between 16384 and 32767 are read as decompression instructions, and all other values are copied literally.

It doesn't need to compress the data as efficiently as possible - it only needs to compress until the output is 6650 or less in length.

While I realize there are numerous compression routines already available that will do a much better job than this would, I need this exact routine for a specific purpose. I just really can't seem to make this work properly.

If there are any good algorithm writers out there, I'd love to hear from you.

Comment: This is not a code-writing service. If you want help, you should detail what you've tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: I didn't even imply that I want someone to write code. Please understand that I'm only seeking assistance - information like how I might implement the matching routine so as to keep it efficient, or other such advice. Assuming is one thing, but jumping to conclusions and then jumping all over someone is quite another. Moving forward, it might be advisable to ask the thread starter if he or she is asking for others to write their code before making uninformed accusations.

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression.  Wikipedia is a good place to start for broad topics.  And welcome to stackoverflow!  You might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: I've looked there and much of it is very thick; an ideal reference to the well-versed in data compression, but not a great learning tool. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: @optimus_subprime you need to look around the site a bit to find out what it's about. Questions need to have some chance of a specific answer, and it's much better if there's some code involved. Asking vaguely how to approach a problem is generally considered off topic, especially in this case since you have a good idea what you want to do but are unsure how to code it.

Comment: Would you be able to recommend another resource in which such a question would not be immediately critcized?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of one, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If you have many repeated values, then simply subtract from every value (except the first) the value that precedes it. You will end up with long runs of zeros. Then compress with a standard compression routine, such as zlib, or gzip on the command line. After decompression, it is then simple to undo the subtractions to recover the original data.

Comment: Read the second-to-last paragraph in the original post.